# How do I sort a list highest to lowest by more then one item in the list?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Honestly it is really hard to explain what I am trying to do because I can't think of words that would help me describe it. Anyway, the problem is that I want to sort a list of lists:

```
[['a', [10, 6, 5]], ['b', [7, 4, 2]], ['c', [10, 6, 4]], ['d', [7, 3, 2]]]
```

This is an example of the list I am trying to sort. The strings are pupil names and the lists with three integers in them are the scores. I want to sort this list highest to lowest using the scores but I want to sort it so if two lists have the same first integer (E.G):

```
[7, 4, 2] and [7, 3, 2]
```

then it should decide which one should be higher by the next integer. I have tried many different methods but from what I have attempted none of them work. Its also been hard trying to find an answer as I do not know exactly how to explain my issue, although I hope what I have said above has given enough explanation to my problem.

My code if you need to look at it:
[MY CODE](http://pastebin.com/bLXFUQtJ)

Comment: `if classfile is '1'` you REALLY want to use `==` there. `is` checks for identical objects. That's NOT what you want here.

Comment: are you sorting by highest score or total and do your lists always have the same lengths?

Comment: Looks like you've got some good answers, but for future reference, please put your code right in your request for assistance.  That guards against a bad link to your code and also makes it available to the next person with the same issue who may stumble on your question sometime down the road after your code has been taken down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument of the `sorted` function, and sort by the second element of each sublist. This will sort from element 0 to element N for each sublist. And the `reverse` argument is so you can sort highest to lowest (instead of the default lowest to highest)

```
>>> l = [['a', [10, 6, 5]], ['b', [7, 4, 2]], ['c', [10, 6, 4]], ['d', [7, 3, 2]]]
>>> sorted(l, key = lambda i: i[1], reverse=True)
[['a', [10, 6, 5]], ['c', [10, 6, 4]], ['b', [7, 4, 2]], ['d', [7, 3, 2]]]
```

You can also replace the `lambda` with `operator.itemgetter(1)` for the key argument as @ThiefMaster pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

You simply specify a key function that returns all the keys you need. In your case the second element of each list (e.g. `[10, 6, 5]`) does the job since comparing lists compares them element by element.

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(whatever, key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

`itemgetter(1)` is the same as `lambda x: x[1]` but more performant (since it's implemented in Python's C code instead of in Python code).

Answer (score 2):

- Sorting in reverse order is supported by the python built-in sorted through a third keyword parameter `reverse`.
- To solve the other problem, where in, the data is sorted based on score rather than the name, which is not in then natural order, can be solved by specifying a custom key, which is supported through the second keyword argument `key`
- The final problem is to order the scores in the manner it appears. This should be left to the natural ordering of Python list.

**Implementation**

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(seq, key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
```

**Output**
    [['a', [10, 6, 5]], ['c', [10, 6, 4]], ['b', [7, 4, 2]], ['d', [7, 3, 2]]]